# Combining shading and transparency in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency, shading

With this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[shading=radial] (0,5) circle (2);
\fill[top color=black] (5,3) rectangle (9,7);
\fill[shading=radial, ultra nearly transparent] (0,0) circle (2);
\fill[top color=black, ultra nearly transparent] (5,-2) rectangle (9,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get (pdf both with mac preview and Adobe Reader) :

[image: transparent shading]

Why does the transparent option almost(but not completely) remove the shading?

Where does the ultra thin perimeter line come from in a pure `\fill` (no `\draw` or `\filldraw`)?

Comment: You need `\shade` not `\fill`.

Comment: @percusse Answer please :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> You need `\shade` not `\fill`.

–  percusse

Result:

[image: result]