# Multiple tikz path fading in multiple directions

Tags: tikz-pgf, theorems, rules

I'd like to create a theorem decoration. Here's a quick take on one:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}
\newcounter{theorem}

\newlength{\theoremrulewidth}
\setlength{\theoremrulewidth}{.4\textwidth}
\newenvironment{theorem}[1][\relax]
  {\refstepcounter{theorem}%
    \tikz[remember picture, overlay] \fill [left color = orange, right color = white, draw = white] 
      (0pt,-.1\baselineskip) -- (0pt,.9\baselineskip) -- (\theoremrulewidth,.9\baselineskip) -- 
        (\theoremrulewidth,\dimexpr.9\baselineskip-1pt) -- (1pt,\dimexpr.9\baselineskip-1pt) -- (1pt,-.1\baselineskip) -- cycle;
   \textcolor{orange}{~\theoremname~\thetheorem}
   \quad}
  {%
   \hfill\null%
   \tikz[remember picture, overlay] \fill [right color = orange, left color = white, draw = white] 
     (0pt,.5\baselineskip) -- (0pt,-.5\baselineskip) -- (-\theoremrulewidth,-.5\baselineskip) -- 
       (-\theoremrulewidth,\dimexpr-.5\baselineskip+1pt) -- (-1pt,\dimexpr-.5\baselineskip+1pt) -- (-1pt,.5\baselineskip) -- cycle;
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem with ascenders and descenders, p-really.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Both horizontal rules fade to `white`. I'd like to also fade both vertical rules to `white`. Would it be possible to fade it to fully transparent `orange`? For the top rule, using a combination of `top color` and `bottom` color in addition to the existing `left color` and `right color` doesn't help; similar for the bottom rule.

Note how I create a polygon of width `1pt` rather than set a regular line. I'm sure there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Draw the vertical rectangles separately and then you can use `top color`, `bottom color`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Yes, I tried that... then there is a not-so pleasant overlay of the two at the connection point due to the `draw=white` option. Even when I set the line width to 0pt, there is a mild artifact in the output... Try it and see, or suggest some alternatives. I'm not that skilled with `tikz`.

Comment: This question http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173538/1952 want similar lines although without corners

Comment: Also this question maybe similar: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134297/31034

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\shade` instead of `\fill` and draw each portion (horizontal component and vertical component) separately; as an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[left color=orange]
  (0,0) -- ++(-4pt,4pt) -- ++(5,0) -- ++(0,-4pt) -- cycle;
\shade[top color=orange]
  (0,0) -- ++(-4pt,4pt) -- ++(0pt,-5) -- ++(4pt,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An here's just the horizontal component, just so that you can see the left end is produced with an angle that then will be completed by the vertical portion:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[left color=orange]
  (0,0) -- ++(-4pt,4pt) -- ++(5,0) -- ++(0,-4pt) -- cycle;
%\shade[top color=orange]
  %(0,0) -- ++(-4pt,4pt) -- ++(0pt,-5) -- ++(4pt,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ha! We had the same idea. Btw, isn't `\shade` simply a shortcut for `\fill[shade]` ?

Comment: @JLDiaz Until today I thought so, but apparently they are not equivalent; using `\fill[shade,...]` instead of `\shade[...]` with my code produces some artifacts.

Comment: @JLDiaz:  `\fill` simply does not work with shade. - I do not know why. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169807/combining-shading-and-transparency-in-tikz

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

[image: Result]

```
\newcommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}
\newcounter{theorem}

\newlength{\theoremrulewidth}
\setlength{\theoremrulewidth}{.4\textwidth}
\newenvironment{theorem}[1][\relax]
  {\refstepcounter{theorem}%
    \tikz[remember picture, overlay, baseline=-.9\baselineskip]{
       \fill[left color = orange, right color = white] 
           (0,0) rectangle +(\theoremrulewidth, -1pt);
       \fill[top color = orange, bottom color = white] 
           (0,0) rectangle +(1pt, -.9\baselineskip);
    }
   \textcolor{orange}{~\theoremname~\thetheorem}
   \quad}
  {%
   \hfill\null%
   \tikz[remember picture, overlay, baseline=0.4\baselineskip] {
       \fill[right color = orange, left color = white] 
           (0,0) rectangle +(-\theoremrulewidth, -1pt);
       \fill[bottom color = orange, top color = white] 
           (0,0) rectangle +(1pt, .9\baselineskip);
  } 
}


\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem with ascenders and descenders, p-really.
\end{theorem}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my try with `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}
\newcounter{theorem}

\newlength{\theoremrulewidth}
\setlength{\theoremrulewidth}{.4\textwidth}
\newenvironment{theorem}[1][\relax]
  {\refstepcounter{theorem}%
    \begin{mybox}%
   \noindent\textcolor{orange}{~\theoremname~\thetheorem}
   \quad}%
  {%
   \hfill\null%
   \end{mybox}
  }

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows}  
  \newtcolorbox{mybox}{%
    enhanced,
    top=0pt,
    left=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    width=\textwidth,
    colframe=white,
    colback=white,
    overlay={
    \draw[thick,orange,path fading=east]([xshift=-0.4pt]frame.north west) rectangle ([xshift=-1cm]frame.north);
    \draw[thick,orange,path fading=south]([xshift=-0.4pt]frame.north west) rectangle (frame.south west);
    \draw[thick,orange,path fading=west]([xshift=-0.4pt]frame.south east) rectangle ([xshift=1cm]frame.south);
    \draw[thick,orange,path fading=north]([xshift=-0.4pt]frame.south east) rectangle (frame.north east);
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem with ascenders and descenders, p-really.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]